# How do I use libcurl with MinGW?

Tags: mingw, libcurl

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPRaS4e.o:test.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From this command

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl -Iinc -Llibcurl.dll test.c -o test.exe
```

**test.c**

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
}
```

I have **test.c** in a folder along with **libcurl.dll** (the Windows 32 bit 7.61.1 binary from [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)) and my **inc** folder. Inside my **inc** folder is the **curl** folder from the **include** folder from **curl-7.61.1.zip**, which I downloaded from the top of [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

What am I doing wrong?